# Local JS in WebView

Tags: react-native

I searched a lot and I didn't find a working solution. I want to execute local JS code in my WebView.
There is a way to accomplish this?
This is the code I tried:

```
class Graph extends Component {

    render() {
        let html = `
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <TITLE> Sample Web Page </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1> THIS IS SAMPLE HEADING IN WEBPAGE. </H1>
    <div id="myContent">This is my name</div>
  <script>
      document.querySelector("#myContent").style.backgroundColor = "red"
    </script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
`;
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <WebView
                style={styles.WebViewStyle}
                source={{html: html}}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}  />
            </View>

        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    WebViewStyle:
        {
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            flex:1,
            marginTop: (Platform.OS) === 'ios' ? 20 : 0
        }
});
```

Comment: This code works fine. [Here](https://snack.expo.io/ryIKMSoiM) is the snack that I have tried. What problems are you facing with?

Comment: I tried on a real android device. Javascript code causes a blank screen in webview. If you remove that javascript part it works.

Comment: Can you please add a function that logs if there is an error? You can use [`onError`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#onerror) property.

Comment: You're right. I'm not sure why, now it works. Still can't make this simple graph example works (blank div)
http://visjs.org/examples/network/basicUsage.html